# powershell script is slow

Tags: performance, powershell

I have a powershell script that is working fine. it does what it is supposed to do.
However it is very slow. If it searches in xlsx and csv files (about 100 files) it takes hours.

Is there a way to make it much faster? I have made a network connection to a sharepoint libary

```css
#Client modules laden (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"   
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.dll"

#Folder om mee verbinding te maken
$Folder = Read-Host -Prompt "Folder (TK8, TK9, TK10)"
$team = Read-Host -Prompt "Team (ICT, CT&M, F&V,D)"
$SourceFolder = "Z:\$Folder\$team"

#Keywords waarop gezocht moet worden
$keyword1 = Read-Host -Prompt "Crebocode (25189, enz.)"
$keyword2 = Read-Host -Prompt "Studentnummer (151510, enz.)"
$keyword3 = Read-Host -Prompt "Cohort (2017, enz.)"

$keyword4 = Read-Host -Prompt "Leerweg (BOL, BBL)"
#$keyword5 = Read-Host -Prompt "Soort product (examenplan, examenproduct)"
$Forward = $true
$MatchWholeWord = $true

#Folder waarheen weggeschreven wordt
$PadDossier = Get-ChildItem  "Z:\Gedeelde  documenten\Examendossiers" | Where name -Like "*$($keyword1)*"
$TargetFolder = "Z:\Gedeelde  documenten\Examendossiers\$($PadDossier.Name)\$($keyword4.ToUpper())\$keyword3\Studentendossiers" 
$TargetFolder1 = Get-ChildItem "Z:\Gedeelde  documenten\Examendossiers\$($PadDossier.Name)\$($keyword4.ToUpper())\$keyword3\Studentendossiers" | Where name -Like "*$($keyword2)*"
$TargetFolder2 = "Z:\Gedeelde  documenten\Examendossiers\$($PadDossier.Name)\$($keyword4.ToUpper())\$keyword3\Studentendossiers\$($TargetFolder1.Name)" 

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*.xls*'-or $_.Name -like '*.csv'}

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $path = $file.FullName
    $objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $objExcel.Visible = $false
    $workBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($path) 
    $sheets = $workBook.Sheets
    $results = @()

      foreach ($sheet in $sheets)
    {
        $sheetName = $sheet.Name
        $filter2 = $workBook.Sheets.Item("$sheetName").UsedRange.Find("$keyword2")
        
        if ($filter2.Text -match $keyword2)
        {
            $results += $true
            write-host -f Cyan $path $sheetName $filter2.Text
            #Copy-Item -Path $path -Destination $destination -Verbose
        }
 #        elseif ($filter2.Text -cnotcontains $MatchWholeWord)
 #   {
        #$word.Application.ActiveDocument.Close()
 #       Write-Host -f Red $path $sheetName $filter2.Text
 #   }
    }
   }
Stop-Process -Name "EXCEL"
```

Comment: Move `$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application` outside of the loop. No need to create Excel Object again and again for each file

Comment: Try measuring each command with a stopwatch (System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch) to see what is taking the most time to run. If you're opening files via WebDAV over a mapped drive from a SharePoint library that could easily be the bottleneck - try copying the files to your local drive first and see if it runs faster from there. If it *does*, at least you know where the problem is...

Comment: @ Hasta Tamang moving it outside the loop helps allready a lot thanks.

Comment: @mclayton Saddely it is no option to copy the files to a local drive. Several users can run the script. I will try the stopwatch to what takes the most time.